# select sum() from multiple table with same column

Tags: mysql

I have a table for product, sales_item and a stock with following structure

## Product table:

```
+----+-----+-------------+
| id |name |description  |
+----+-----+-------------+
| 1  |Pr1  |prod1        |
+----+-----+-------------+
| 2  |Pr2  |prod2        |
+----+-----+-------------+
| .. |...  |.....        |
+----+-----+-------------+
```

**sales_item_details table**

```
+-----+----------+------------+-----+
| id  | sales_id | product_id | qty |
+-----+----------+------------+-----+
| 517 |      211 |          1 | 200 |
+-----+----------+------------+-----+
| 518 |      211 |          1 | 120 |
+-----+----------+------------+-----+
```

and **production**

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id | product_id | qty   |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 |          1 |    20 |
|  2 |          2 |   200 |
|  3 |          1 |    20 |
|  4 |          3 |    30 |
|  5 |          9 |    30 |
|  6 |         65 |    10 |
|  7 |         65 |    50 |
|  8 |         71 |    10 |
|  9 |         71 |    10 |
| 10 |         71 |    10 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

And now I am creating multiple database with same table defination and need to maintain stock

**production** table and **product** table will be maintained from single database
only **sales_item_details** table will be different but product id will same

So how will be the query to get SUM(qty) of sales item details and view the inventory in stock

I have tried this:

```
SELECT
        `pr`.`id`,
        `pr`.`name`,
        sl.size,
        IFNULL(SUM(s.qty), 0) AS sales,
        IFNULL((SELECT SUM(qty) FROM production st WHERE st.product_id = `pr`.`product-id`), 0) AS stock_added
    FROM products pr
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT qty, product_id FROM db1.sales_item_details
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT qty, product_id FROM db2.sales_item_details 
        ) s ON pr.`id` = s.product_id
        LEFT JOIN size_list sl ON sl.id = `pr`.`product-size`
    GROUP BY s.product_id
    ORDER BY sales DESC
```

but getting the product which is sold

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: Possible Duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432178/how-can-i-sum-columns-across-multiple-tables-in-mysql

Comment: 'Multiple database' ?? Why ??

Comment: @hiule MySQL does not support the `pivot` statement.

Comment: I do not get the multiple databases design either.

Comment: I am creating multiple database having those table but the product and production table will be same as db1 but only sales_item_details table will be different drom db1. Thanks @Shadow

Comment: I understand what you are doing, just do not get it **why**.

Comment: I am creating because i need to create multiple brand and that needed bill number starting from 1 for each brand. I am creating billing application, @Shadow

Comment: Ouch. No, you do not need multiple dbs for this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571125/custom-serial-autoincrement-per-group-of-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st I created a view holding all sales items grouped by product id in the main database:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW unit_sold_all  AS
    SELECT 
        p.`product-id` AS product_id,
        (
            (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(s0.qty), 0) FROM db_1.sales_item_details s0 WHERE s0.product_id = p.`product-id`) + 
            (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(s1.qty), 0) FROM db_2.sales_item_details s1 WHERE s1.product_id = p.`product-id`) + 
            (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(s2.qty), 0) FROM db_3.sales_item_details s2 WHERE s2.product_id = p.`product-id`) + 
            (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(s3.qty), 0) FROM db_4.sales_item_details s3 WHERE s3.product_id = p.`product-id`) + 
            (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(s4.qty), 0) FROM db_5.sales_item_details s4 WHERE s4.product_id = p.`product-id`) 
        ) as total_unit_sales
FROM products p
```

Then in another sql, I selected the sum of the sales.

***PS: I answered this question myself because this might need by another person in the future.***