# How to Join two tables and sum their columns across in Mysql based on distinct column

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

I am joining two tables by the regNo column. I want to add the points of Table1.points and Table2.points where the regNo matches and just incase it doesn't match I also want it be included with its points in the list as shown in the image bellow
[image: expected results From the two table1& table2]

I have read through the existing problems but not finding the solution to this e.g [How can I sum columns across multiple tables in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432178/how-can-i-sum-columns-across-multiple-tables-in-mysql)

```
(
    SELECT `Ex`.regNo,(`In`.`points`+`Ex`.`points`) AS 'Points' 
    FROM Table1`In` 
    LEFT JOIN Table2`Ex` ON `In`.`regNo` = `In`.`regNo`
)
UNION
(
    SELECT`Ex`.regNo,(`In`.`points`+`Ex`.`points`) AS 'Points' 
    FROM Table1`In` 
    RIGHT JOIN Table2`Ex` ON `In`.`regNo` = `In`.`regNo`
);
```

I want it to give the list arranged as per unique (DISTINCT) regNo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `UNION` followed by `GRoUP BY`:

```
SELECT regNo, SUM(points) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT regNo, points
    FROM Table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT regNo, points
    FROM Table2
) AS u
GROUP BY regNo
```

Comment: Thanks alot this was so simple and worked well with my case.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `FULL JOIN` between both tables.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) id
    COALESCE(t1.regNo, t2.regNo) regNo
    COALESCE(t1.points, 0) +  COALESCE(t2.points 0) points
FROM
    table1 t1
    FULL JOIN table2 t2 on t1.regNo = t2.regNo
```

NB : you did not specify what you expect to be done to generate the new `id` so by default the above query will display the `table1.id` if available, else `table2.id`.

If you would better generate a new, auto-incremented field, then :

```
SET @i=0;
SELECT 
    @i:=@i+1 id
    COALESCE(t1.regNo, t2.regNo) regNo
    COALESCE(t1.points, 0) +  COALESCE(t2.points 0) points
FROM
    table1 t1
    FULL JOIN table2 t2 on t1.regNo = t2.regNo
```

Comment: I am not Much interested in Id generation. I just want that unique regNo and the sum from both tables as shown above

Comment: @JOB ok so the first query should to the job just fine

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. You need to use `full outer join` and null replacement before aggregation

```
select 
   COALESCE(table1.regno, table2.regno) regno,
   sum(COALESCE(table1.points,0)) + sum(COALESCE(table2.points,0)) points
from Table1 
full outer join Table2 
  on table1.regno = table2.regno
group by 
  COALESCE(table1.regno, table2.regno)
```